# Manhwa about siblings who escape imprisonment thanks to the sister's powers

Tags: story-identification, manga

I don't remember many details but basically it's about a girl and her little brother being imprisoned. They manage to escape thanks to the sister who has powers. I remember a scene where she controlled the prison bars to move to defend herself.

If I'm not mistaken they are both noble/royalty.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you remember the names of any of the characters or places?

Comment: Heyy , thank u . No I don't remember anything else 

Comment: Do you recall the hair colour of the sister or brother?

Comment: I hesitate between pink or blond

Answer (score 1):

This is [The Forgotten Princess Just Wants Peace](https://manta.net/en/series/the-forgotten-princess-just-wants-peace?seriesId=1912).

> I'm the daughter of a Duke?! While locked up in a prison cell, Eluana Vita awakens her alchemy powers and later finds out she's the daughter of a Duke! However, she's in for a rude awakening when she realizes the royal life isn't what she thought it'd be.

The screenshot below is the scene you are talking about.

[image: Scene]